# SQL CASE statement with OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have to following:

```
Select OrderID = 
    Case OrderID 
        When 1 Then 'Customer1'
        When 2 Then 'Customer2'
        When 3 Then 'Customer2'
        Else 'Unknown Customer'
    End 
From OrdersPlaced
```

Is it possible to add an or and do something along the lines of:

```
Select OrderID = 
    Case OrderID 
        When 1 Then 'Customer1'
        When 2 Or 3 Then 'Customer2'
        Else 'Unknown Customer'
    End 
From OrdersPlaced
```

Comment: why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Well I obviously tried my exact Code and got the error on the Or. I wasn't asking if my code would work, I was asking how I would do it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two forms of [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression, 'searched' and 'simple'. You can't use an `OR` with a 'simple' `CASE` expression, but you can with the 'searched' form:

```
Case  
    When OrderID = 1 Then 'Customer1'
    When OrderID = 2 Or
         OrderID = 3 Then 'Customer2'
    Else 'Unknown Customer'
End
```

Or even

```
Case  
    When OrderID = 1 Then 'Customer1'
    When OrderID IN (2, 3) Then 'Customer2'
    Else 'Unknown Customer'
End
```

Comment: But is this going to be optimized? Or will it have to pull `OrderID` inside of each case? My though process was the method I was using was Grabbing OrderID once, and using that temp variable to test against. Are these methods now going to have to pull OrderID for each test? Would I be better of leaving my original code? Or am I complelty wrong and the server handles all of these the same?

Comment: even furthur more from the Documentation of MSDN `a simple CASE expression allows for only an equality check; no other comparisons are made` when your answer seems to be more `searched CASE expression allows for values to be replaced in the result set based on comparison values`, Would it not be slower using a comparison vs equality check?

Comment: From the structure that you've showed us so far I believe it will only 'pull' the column once when analyzing each result row, regardless of how many times it appears in the `SELECT` clause. However, I'll admit that I'm not an expert on SQL Server optimization, so there might be some subtleties to this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @user2125348 Also, `OrderID = 1` and `OrderID IN (2, 3)` *are* equality checks, but yes, a searched `CASE` expression may be slower in some situations since it will have to go through each `WHEN` expression until it finds a match, whereas the the simple `CASE` could implement something like a [branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) for speed instead. It might also be faster in a few situations because you have tighter control over the order of execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use alternative form of CASE

```
Select OrderID = 
    Case 
        When OrderID = 1 Then 'Customer1'
        When OrderID = 2 Or OrderID = 3 Then 'Customer2'
        Else 'Unknown Customer'
    End 
From OrdersPlaced
```

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` expression has two kinds of syntax - the simple (i.e. one that you are showing), and the searched, with multiple logical conditions. If you would like to use an `OR`, you need the second kind:

```
Select OrderID = 
    Case 
        When OrderID =1 Then 'Customer1'
        When OrderID =2 Or OrderID =3 Then 'Customer2'
        Else 'Unknown Customer'
    End 
From OrdersPlaced
```

Here is the description from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

- The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
- The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

Comment: So, my original example would be the best performing as it is an equality check and not a Boolean comparison? Even if only for this small example?

Comment: @user2125348 The difference in `CASE` statements would have no discernible difference, because it does not change the number of I/Os required to complete the query. [See this answer for more info on the performance impact of `CASE` expressions in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012987/335858).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This would work for your scenario.

```
Select OrderID = 
    Case
        When OrderID  = 1 Then 'Customer1'
        When OrderID in (2, 3) Then 'Customer2'
        Else 'Unknown Customer'
    End 
From OrdersPlaced
```